# Is $n + ||\text{roots} \left( \frac{d^n f}{d x^n} \right) ||$ an upper bound for $||\text{roots}( f(x) )||$?

Tags: calculus

Is $n$ plus the number of roots of the nth derivative, an upper bound for the number of roots of $f(x)$, assuming $f$ is a continuous, differentiable Real function, and the nth derivative is not the zero function?

Is there a similar, general purpose rule for the lower bound on the number of roots of $f(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

According to #math on Freenode, my question is a (poor) rephrasing of Rolle's Theorem, includes the statement that $f^\prime (x)$ has no more than $|| \text{roots}( f(x) ) || - 1$ roots.